# How do you disable touch to screen without using beginIgnoringInteractionEvents?

Tags: iphone, touch

from [a similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101965/how-can-i-disable-the-touch-detection)

> You could always put a transparent UIView over top of the area you
>   want to "disable" tap input for, have it listen for taps, and have it
>   ignore them. Remove the UIView (or hide it) when you want input to be
>   listened to again.

Now, I can understand the strategy, but would someone enlighten me with a code?

How do you make a view
1. listen for taps
2. have it ignore them

Would it not pass touch to views behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a plain UIView's `userInteractionEnabled` property to YES, but don't have any code in there to respond to touch events. The view will then 'swallow' all touches.