# Get reference to left button in TableViewController from StoryBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have an issue in a storyboard with the back button.

The storyboard is defined as this:
[image]

My problem is that after pushing the segue, I can't get any reference for the back button.
My `viewcontroller` is inheriting from the `UITableViewController` class.

I already tried the usual suspects:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem, self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.
```

In all of them the reference is nil.

In the `viewDidLoad` of the `SettinsViewController` I do only this:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:[CredentialTableViewCell nibName] bundle:nil]
     forCellReuseIdentifier:[CredentialTableViewCell reuseIdentifier]];

self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = HEXCOLOR(0xebf2f9ff);
```

I do nothing when pushing the segue, the back button is automatically generated with the previous view controller title instead of taking my "Back" title and I can't get a reference to it.

Does anyone know how can I get the reference for this automatically generated back button?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a sanity check, your TableViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController, right? It's a little hard to tell from the image.

Secondly, I the Back button is actually an attribute of the view that *pushes* the view controller onto the screen. So if you want to work with the back button that is displayed to the user, you need to ask the ViewController *that pushed* the current view for it's back button.

From the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If the top-level view controller does not have a custom left bar button item, but the navigation item of the previous view controller has a valid item in its backBarButtonItem property, the navigation bar displays that item.

Therefore, to get your back button to say "Back", change the **Back Button** field of the **Previous** view controller (the one that pushes your Settings View Controller).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a navigation controller, and I understand your suggestion. However I don't know why the back button is nil even in the parent, but if I do parentViewController.navigationBar.items, I do get the two navigation items, is just that the left one is not a button as I would need(I need to temporarily disable it).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to lock all the interface instead of only that button, was wasting too much time in a little detail.

I did like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Found the suggestion in this answer: [How can I disable the touch detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101965/how-can-i-disable-the-touch-detection)